# Intermittent WCF error: Collection already contains an address with scheme http

Tags: wcf

I get this intermittent WCF error:

This collection already contains an address with scheme http.  There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection.
Parameter name: item

I tried various solutions by from googling around and from stackoverflow and they work for a while until the error shows up again and then I attempt another solution.  It is really frustrating.  Right now this is all voodoo to me as I don't understand why this is happening.  It appears that if I touch the webconfig file and save it, the error disappears.   I don't know if this causes it, but my webconfig is nested in that it lives under a special webservices folder.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What are the contents of your system.servicemodel configuration group?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at how your IIS bindings are defined/configured in the IIS .config file located at...

> C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config

Find your way to the Sites-Site-Bindings section, then look for bindings that have the same protocol defined. Example:

```
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:80:" />
<binding protocol="net.tcp" bindingInformation="8081:*" />
<binding protocol="net.pipe" bindingInformation="*" />
<binding protocol="net.msmq" bindingInformation="localhost" />
<binding protocol="msmq.formatname" bindingInformation="localhost" />
<binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:" />
<binding protocol="net.tcp" bindingInformation="9000:*" />
```

Notice there are two bindings for the "net.tcp" protocol. The above example configuration will throw the following error:

> This collection already contains an address with scheme net.tcp. There can be at most one address per scheme in this collection. Paramter name: item

I personally experienced this error when I added the net.tcp protocol using the command prompt (as opposed to IIS Manager):

> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set site "Default Web Site" -+bindings.[protocol-'net.tcp',bindinginformation-'9000:*']

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one http base endpoints (i.e. WsHttpBinding and BasicHttpBinding) and trying to add them at the same time, you will get this error.

Comment: Do you have two http addresses then? If so try to host them separately and not in a same Uri[].

Comment: Thanks Mohammadreza.  Looks like this is what I have to do.  I do have the a subfolder called webservices that contains a separate web.config.  It contains all the WCF settings.